# Sort sublists according to the corresponding weight in another sublist in python

Tags: python, numpy, nested-lists

I have the two nested lists `list1` and `list2`. `list1` represents sublists of values that I need to sort, according to the second sublists in `list2` that represent the weights of `list1`:

```
list1 = [[0.002, 0.001, 0.002, 0.1, 0.001, 0.2, 0.03, 0.04, 0.002, 0.03, 0.004, 0.0004, 0.005, 0.05],
         [0.007, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.02, 0.0003, 0.007, 0.007, 0.008, 0.0006, 0.0004, 0.005, 0.05],
         [0.0009, 0.000, 0.0002, 0.9, 0.091, 0.2, 0.03, 0.04, 0.002, 0.03, 0.004, 0.0004, 0.005, 0.0009],
         [0.002, 0.001, 0.002, 0.1, 0.001, 0.2, 0.03, 0.04, 0.002, 0.03, 0.004, 0.0004, 0.005, 0.055]]
   


  list2 =[[0.06165411, 0.04111233, 0.06165411, 0.049487340000000005, 0.04111233, 0.020541780000000003, 0.04111233, 0.020541780000000003, 0.06165411, 0.04111233, 0.020541780000000003, 0.0, 0.0, 0.049487340000000005], 
          [0.29708409, 0.19810227000000002, 0.049487340000000005, 0.19810227000000002, 0.020541780000000003, 0.09898182000000001, 0.09898182000000001, 0.29708409, 0.29708409, 0.09898182000000001, 0.09898182000000001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.049487340000000005], 
          [0.19810227000000002, 0.09898182000000001, 0.049487340000000005, 0.09898182000000001, 0.09898182000000001, 0.020541780000000003, 0.04111233, 0.020541780000000003, 0.020541780000000003, 0.04111233, 0.020541780000000003, 0.0, 0.0, 0.19810227000000002], 
          [0.06165411, 0.04111233, 0.06165411, 0.049487340000000005, 0.04111233, 0.020541780000000003, 0.04111233, 0.020541780000000003, 0.06165411, 0.04111233, 0.020541780000000003, 0.0, 0.0, 0.09898182000000001]]
```

I want to sort each sublist in `list1` according to the corresponding **sorted sublist** in `list2`. I have written the following code:

```
def sort_list(list1, list2):
    z = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(list2, list1))]
    return(z)

sort_fea = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    c1 = list1[i]
    c2 = list2[i]
    sort_fea.append(sort_list(c1, c2))
print('The sorted_list1 =',sort_fea)
```

And I get on the following correct result:

```
sorted_list1 =[[0.0004, 0.005, 0.004, 0.04, 0.2, 0.001, 0.001, 0.03, 0.03, 0.05, 0.1, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002],
               [0.0004, 0.005, 0.001, 0.0002, 0.05, 0.0003, 0.0006, 0.008, 0.02, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007],
               [0.0004, 0.005, 0.002, 0.004, 0.04, 0.2, 0.03, 0.03, 0.0002, 0.0, 0.091, 0.9, 0.0009, 0.0009],
               [0.0004, 0.005, 0.004, 0.04, 0.2, 0.001, 0.001, 0.03, 0.03, 0.1, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.055]]
```

Are there any faster methods using `numpy` or any other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe solution with `pandas` will be faster:

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [[0.002, 0.001, 0.002, 0.1, 0.001, 0.2, 0.03, 0.04, 0.002, 0.03, 0.004, 0.0004, 0.005, 0.05],
         [0.007, 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.02, 0.0003, 0.007, 0.007, 0.008, 0.0006, 0.0004, 0.005, 0.05],
         [0.0009, 0.000, 0.0002, 0.9, 0.091, 0.2, 0.03, 0.04, 0.002, 0.03, 0.004, 0.0004, 0.005, 0.0009],
         [0.002, 0.001, 0.002, 0.1, 0.001, 0.2, 0.03, 0.04, 0.002, 0.03, 0.004, 0.0004, 0.005, 0.055]]

list2 =[[0.06165411, 0.04111233, 0.06165411, 0.049487340000000005, 0.04111233, 0.020541780000000003, 0.04111233, 0.020541780000000003, 0.06165411, 0.04111233, 0.020541780000000003, 0.0, 0.0, 0.049487340000000005],
          [0.29708409, 0.19810227000000002, 0.049487340000000005, 0.19810227000000002, 0.020541780000000003, 0.09898182000000001, 0.09898182000000001, 0.29708409, 0.29708409, 0.09898182000000001, 0.09898182000000001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.049487340000000005],
          [0.19810227000000002, 0.09898182000000001, 0.049487340000000005, 0.09898182000000001, 0.09898182000000001, 0.020541780000000003, 0.04111233, 0.020541780000000003, 0.020541780000000003, 0.04111233, 0.020541780000000003, 0.0, 0.0, 0.19810227000000002],
          [0.06165411, 0.04111233, 0.06165411, 0.049487340000000005, 0.04111233, 0.020541780000000003, 0.04111233, 0.020541780000000003, 0.06165411, 0.04111233, 0.020541780000000003, 0.0, 0.0, 0.09898182000000001]]

df = pd.DataFrame({'l1': list1, 'l2': list2}).apply(pd.Series.explode)
out = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(['l2', 'l1'])['l1'].values.tolist()).tolist()

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[[0.0004, 0.005, 0.004, 0.04, 0.2, 0.001, 0.001, 0.03, 0.03, 0.05, 0.1, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002], 
 [0.0004, 0.005, 0.001, 0.0002, 0.05, 0.0003, 0.0006, 0.008, 0.02, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007], 
 [0.0004, 0.005, 0.002, 0.004, 0.04, 0.2, 0.03, 0.03, 0.0002, 0.0, 0.091, 0.9, 0.0009, 0.0009], 
 [0.0004, 0.005, 0.004, 0.04, 0.2, 0.001, 0.001, 0.03, 0.03, 0.1, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.055]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sort_fea = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    result = [x for _, x in sorted(zip(list2[i], list1[i]))]
    sort_fea.append(result)
print(sort_fea)
```

Output:

```
[[0.0004, 0.005, 0.004, 0.04, 0.2, 0.001, 0.001, 0.03, 0.03, 0.05, 0.1, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002],
 [0.0004, 0.005, 0.001, 0.0002, 0.05, 0.0003, 0.0006, 0.008, 0.02, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007],
 [0.0004, 0.005, 0.002, 0.004, 0.04, 0.2, 0.03, 0.03, 0.0002, 0.0, 0.091, 0.9, 0.0009, 0.0009],
 [0.0004, 0.005, 0.004, 0.04, 0.2, 0.001, 0.001, 0.03, 0.03, 0.1, 0.002, 0.002, 0.002, 0.055]]
```

As far as I know, this will speed-up your code.

Comment: Thank you Ahmet Tavli for you answer. Only one problem is that the result by your code is continuous list, whereas, I need the result as the original  list of sublists as like sort_fea = [ [ , , ...], [ , , .....] , ...........]

Comment: Could you please look at my new edited answer? I think and I hope the answer will solve your problem.